# After configuring CORS webpage returns error but also results

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cors, backend

I'm creating a simple ASP.NET backend, and I need to enable CORS to whitelist only my website (from which the requests come), while it should be unreachable from any other source. I've done that like in the image below (and I honestly tried every other way I know without success), and what I achieved is that when making any request (GET, PUT, POST...) I always get no problems from the whitelisted website (and this is fine), but I also get response from other sources, while I only have a CORS generic error on browser console (I repeat, while getting the error I also get the answer, which I don't want).
What should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Matteo

```
 public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://myclient"));
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
            .AddDbContext<WebApiContext>(options => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Configuration.WebRootPath}/tutoriel.db"));            

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowMyOrigin"));
        }); //Imposta il cors su tutto il progetto (resource: DZone)
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


        });
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://mysite", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://mysite: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
core.js:15724
```

**Warning:**

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://mysite with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

an anauthorized site request error

but Json result showed

```
{"id":"w.paciaroni","luogo":"giappone","disponibilita":false}
```

Comment: Try http: //myclient instead of https. Then call the API with https if you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I repeat, while getting the error I also get the answer

This is expected behavior. CORS is a **browser** security feature. It's designed to protect the **user**, not your server, against cross-site scripting attacks.

> which I don't want

Then you'll have to implement that on the server. The easiest way is to write a middleware or an ActionFilter that checks the `Origin` header of the request. If it doesn't match any of your allowed origins, return an error response (I recommend error status [412 Precondition Failed](https://httpstatuses.com/412)).

Security note: an attacker can easily spoof the Origin header, so this will only
stop the dumbest of hackers from accessing your webpage.